# How do I convert byte[] to Bitmap?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a byte buffer and how do I get Bitmap?

Comment: What kind of bitmap are you talking about?

Comment: And what is Bitmap? It's not a standard Java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the image, use `ImageIO`. It creates a format-agnostic image in memory:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

If you just want to store in to disk, then simply write the byte array to a file.

Note that the byte array must be already a bitmap image, you can't take any byte array and have it as bitmap.

And you get the byte array from the byte buffer by:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[buf.capacity()];
buf.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```