# Working with an uncompressed bitmap byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, xamarin

Currently I am trying sending an uncompressed bitmap byte array to a third party library, when I get this byte array back I would like to convert it back to a Bitmap.

Currently a working solution is to loop over the byte array and draw pixel by pixel into a bitmap but obviously the performance for this is terrible.

The question is: how can I convert an uncompressed byte array to bitmap in the quickest way possible?

Comment: try Bitmap.create() with int[] colors parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(byte[] pixels, int width, int height) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    byte[] imgData = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(pixels, 0, imgData, 0, pixels.length);
    return image;
}
```

Depending on your byte order and alpha channel you will need another image type, e.g. `BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`

Comment: Does not require another package. pls consider upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this method ; it worked!

```
public static Drawable byteToDrawable(byte[] data) {

    if (data == null)
        return null;
    else
        return new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length));
}
```

it returns a drawable...

I think it will help you.

Comment: BitmapFactory requires the Android package

Comment: See the answer of this question : [How do I convert bytes to Bitmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007770/how-do-i-convert-byte-to-bitmap)